# set attribute of child node

Tags: javascript, xml

how would i add an attribute to the "testTwo" tag?
Javascript noob..

```
        var XML = document.createElement("test");
        var Node = document.createElement("testOne");
        Node.setAttribute("id", "0");
        Node.setAttribute("random", "0"); 
        Node.appendChild( document.createElement("testTwo"));

        XML.appendChild(Node);

        console.log(XML.innerHTML);
```

Comment: In ***absolutely*** the same way as to `testOne`.

Comment: how? Node.appendChild(document.createElement("testTow").setAttribute("","")? i tried this it doesn't work... or do you mean Node.setAttribute but after i create testTwo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `testTwo` node beforehand.  Example code would be :

```js
var XML = document.createElement("test");
var Node = document.createElement("testOne");
Node.setAttribute("id", "0");
Node.setAttribute("random", "0"); 
var testtwo = document.createElement("testTwo");
testtwo.setAttribute("attr", "attrval");
Node.appendChild(testtwo);

XML.appendChild(Node);

console.log(XML.innerHTML);
```

Comment: no problemo ;) ... I'm still learning JS myself, it's a never ending thing

Answer (score 1):

You have the right technique for the first node.  Use the same thing to the 2nd node.  Create your 2nd node (testTwo) before appending it somewhere.  Create the node with all the attributes you want associated with it.  Then once that is all done the way you want, then `append` it to the parent node you want.

Here would be what the code would look like.

```js
var XML = document.createElement("test");
var Node = document.createElement("testOne");
Node.setAttribute("id", "0");
Node.setAttribute("random", "0"); 

//Create the 2nd node first
var node2 = document.createElement("testTwo");
//add the attributes you want for this node
node2.setAttribute("key", "value");
node2.setAttribute("key2", "value2");
//once you're done append it.
Node.appendChild( node2 );

XML.appendChild(Node);

console.log(XML.innerHTML);
```